# Xcode error when uploading to App Store: “Invalid Bundle structure”

Tags: ios, xcode, native, nativescript

I'm using Xcode to build a native script app for iOS. I've registered an app on iTunes Connect.

when I build the application on Xcode its works well.

All goes well in Xcode until I upload to the App Store. I get the following error:
[image]

[image]

Comment: check your dependency list in `package.json` and make sure there are no `devDependency` packages added there

Comment: @Nick :do I remove all the devDependency from package .json?

Comment: Nope - just make sure that you are not using a `devDependency` as a `dependency` - this sometimes is causing the error above. You could also try this solution https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/invalid-bundle-structure-your-app-can-t-contain-standalone-executables-or-libraries/4482

Comment: Here  the same issue was caused by node-sass as a dependency https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-sass/issues/3

Comment: @Nick thanks for quick reply, But I think here is the problem from fse.code, what do you think, I'm new in Native Script

Comment: @nick: please see my attach second screeshot.when I tried to Archeive the app through XCode it show like this.

Comment: @nick : I'm tried after the remove the dependencies but it doesn't work still showing same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is related with devDependencies, Since error is showing invalid bundle structure this is because some of your devDependencies is added in the dependencies object inside package.json.

In your case  "nativescript-dev-sass": "^1.0.0-rc.2" dependency was added in your package.json just move it from dependecy to devDependency.

Answer (score -1):

Open the project in Finder and search if you have added any .framework file in Project directory besides pod folder. Delete the .framwork file and build,archive again.